# Objective-C: inheriting protected/private atomic property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Say, I have classes C, D which are defined next way:

```
@interface C:NSObject 
@end

@interface D:C 
@end
```

My goal is to add **atomic** property P to the class C in such way that it will be visible and usable inside class D (and its derivatives) **only**.

what is the best way to do that?

**PS** The property **MUST** be atomic in D.

Comment: What you want isn't directly supported by Objective-C. If it's in class `C` and visible to `D` and its subclasses then it is visible to any class that subclasses `C`. See the iOS class `UIGestureRecognizer` and its subclassing notes for an example of how Apple handles this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support of protected properties or methods in Objective-C. However, there is a way to do it by convention. Like abstract methods - if someone wants he can violate it easily.

You define the property that you want to be protected in the `.m` file.

```
@interface DemoObject ()
    @property NSString *protectedString;
@end

@implementation DemoObject
    //implementation of the class
@end
```

The property is *atomic* - it's a default.

Then you inherit from `DemoObject`:

`.h` file

```
@interface InheritingObject : DemoObject

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface DemoObject ()

    @property NSString *protectedString;

@end

@implementation InheritingObject
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        self.protectedString = @"Some String";
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

What basically has happened here is that we created an extension of the `DemoObject` that exposes the property we need to the `InheritingObject`. Any object that uses `DemoObject` does not see the `protectedString` property, because it is not defined in its `.h` file. The classes that see the property are those which define the `DemoObject`'s extension.

Actually you can expose a property in this way to *any* class, not only derived one. So it's easy to break this convention. However, it creates some sort of order and an illusion of protected scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can have that without repetition and therefore much easier to handle:

C.h:

```
@interface C : NSObject
…
@end
```

**Create another header file:**

C_Protected:

```
@interface C()
@property id protecedVisibility;
@end
```

C.m

```
@import "C.h"
@import "C_Protected.h" // You have to do this for correct implementation
```

D.m:

```
#import "C.h"
#import "C_Protected.h"
```

Then you can easily edit the protected part.